# SQL Getting the party with highest votes

Tags: mysql, sql, voting-system

I am trying to make a voting system through a SQL server, and I can't get it right. What I am trying to do is get the party with the highest amount of votes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Vote 
    INNER JOIN Members ON Vote.Voted = Members.PartyName 
WHERE (PartyName is the biggest one)
```

I expect something like [DEMS][8], or at the very least, the party name of the party with the highest votes.

[image]

Comment: Does one assume that something in your data corresponds to "party" and to "votes"?  It is not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a WHERE clause you need to use whatever the syntax is for the top record in your SQL dialect. You also need to group by partijnaam. This is a bit of a guess as I don;t know your exact data structure.

**Postgres/MySQL**

```
SELECT PartijNaam, COUNT(*) 
FROM stem 
    INNER JOIN leden ON stem.Gestemt = Leden.lidnummer 
GROUP BY PartijNaam
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT TOP 1 PartijNaam, COUNT(*) 
FROM stem 
    INNER JOIN leden ON stem.Gestemt = Leden.lidnummer
GROUP BY PartijNaam
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I have added a picture of the 2 tables and their relation. stem meaning vote and leden meaning member gestemt means the member number they have voted on. also i have tried what you suggested but it gave blank results

Comment: Looks like the join is wrong then. Still guessing somewhat but it seems like you want to join gestemt to lidnumber, are they both the member number?

Comment: yes that is becouse when you have voted you vote for a member of the party so they are linked. when i want to check the votes for a member you just count the "gestemt"

Answer (score 0):

SELECT PartijNaam FROM leden INNER JOIN stem ON leden.LidNummer = stem.Gestemt GROUP BY PartijNaam ORDER BY COUNT(gestemt) DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  SELECT  PartijNaam, COUNT(*)as vote 
    FROM stem 
        INNER JOIN leden ON stem.Gestemt = Leden.lidnummer
    GROUP BY PartijNaam
    ORDER BY DESC
```